# Multiple MySQL statements via JDBC sampler in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

So I am trying to update my database using the data extracted from the HTTP request samplers. So I have the following sql query which works fine for one record:

```
UPDATE optim_user
SET equip_uptime = CONCAT('${timestamp_rg1}', ',', '${timestamp_ext1}'), equip_fw = CONCAT('${firmware_rg1}',',', '${firmware_ext1}')
WHERE optim_uid = '${serialnumber_soak1}';
```

I want to update 50 or so records with the data extracted from my hTTP requests. 
I have tried following the steps mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34133362/how-to-run-multiple-mysql-statements-via-jdbc-sampler-in-jmeter) but It did not work. Below are the screen shots of the CSV data config and the JDBC sampler[image][image]

Is there a way to include multiple sql statements? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`case` for multiple updates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3432/multiple-updates-in-mysql).in your case add multiple conditions as:

```
 UPDATE optim_user
 SET equip_uptime = case   optim_uid 
 WHEN   '${serialnumber_soak1}'  THEN 
 CONCAT('${timestamp_rg1}', ',', '${timestamp_ext1}')
 End

  .....
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax of referencing a JMeter Variable would be either [`${statement}`](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#functions) or [`${__V(statement)}`](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__V).

Also if your CSV file contains references to other JMeter functions and/or variables you will additionally need to wrap it into [__eval() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__eval) so my expectation is that you need to come up with something like:

```
${__eval(${statement})}
```

See [Here’s What to Do to Combine Multiple JMeter Variables](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/here%E2%80%99s-what-do-combine-multiple-jmeter-variables) article for more details.